# Compile a template without passing scope

Tags: angularjs

### Question

In AngularJS, is there a way to convert a string template into markup **without** using `scope` or a directive?

### Explanation

I have a service which allows me to create new angular apps dynamically. It builds up the DOM for the new app, then runs `angular.boostrap` on the element.

Currently, the DOM is created like this:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.setAttribute('app', '');
element.setAttribute('size', 'small');
...
element.className = 'app layout--relative';
```

There are many **attributes**, **classes**, **child elements**, etc, so creating the markup in this way is not ideal. **It would be better to use a template.**

Normally I would use `$compile` to convert a string template into markup, but because I have not run `angular.bootstrap` yet, there is no `scope` in order to use `$compile(template)(scope);`

### What I have tried

#### Create a div, then replace the innerHTML with the template string

This works, but all of the attributes and classes on the root element need to be added separately.

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = template;
```

#### Remove scope after the template has compiled

This works, but I would prefer to avoid scope altogether:

```
var scope = $rootScope.$new();
var element = $compile(template)(scope);
scope.$destroy();
```

Comment: It seems you don't need a real compile, but a string substitution to convert a template into a usable html markup. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I want a template string to convert to html markup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `$interpolate` service for string substitution like this:

```
var template = '<div app size="{{size}}" class="{{className}}">' +
                 '<span>Hello {{name}}!</span>' +
               '</div>';

$interpolate(template)({
  size: 'small',
  className: 'app layout--relative',
  name: 'World'
});
```

and the result would be like this:

```
<div app size="small" class="app layout--relative">
  <span>Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.