# Compile angular directive template without dom

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to get the compiled angular directive html-code without the dom?

This is what I want:

```
var scope = {
        list: ["Peter","Paul","Mary"]
    },
    template = '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in list"{{item}}</li><ul>',
    result;

result = desiredFunction( scope, template );

// result should be: "<ul><li>Peter</li><li>Paul</li><li>Mary</li></ul>"
```

Is there a possibility to get the `desiredFunction`?

**EDIT:**

To make my wish a little bit clearer: I want to "compile" an angular directive template string **without having to push the directive into the dom**, because I do not want to have it in the dom. I even do not want a directive anyway. What I only want is the compiled string  from a template string ( template-string + scope-object ==> html-string).

Is there any Angular-internal or even external (library) way to do this?

**EDIT (2):**

Taking NewDev's answer, correcting my html template and adding a `$timeout` leads me to the following solution, which works:

```
    $scope.list = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"];
    var template = '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li></ul>';
    var jqElem = angular.element(template);
    $compile(jqElem)($scope);
    $timeout( function() {
        console.log( jqElem.html() );
    });
```

**EDIT (3):**

Following zerflagL's comment this is also possible (and even shorter):

```
    $scope.list = ["Peter", "Paul", "Mary"];
    var template = '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in list">{{item}}</li></ul>';
    var result = $compile(template)($scope)[0];
    $timeout( function() {
        console.log( result );
    });
```

Comment: in the link function, you can just return `element.html()`, no? am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile without the element being in the DOM.

Assuming you have proper injections, you could do:

```
var template = '<ul><li ng-repeat="item in list"{{item}}</li><ul>';
var jqElem = angular.element("<div>").html(template);
$compile(jqElem)($scope);
```

At this point, however, the `innerHTML` is still not compiled. For that, we need to wait until the end of $digest cycle. One way I know how to do this is to use $timeout, but that means that your function would have to return a promise

```
return $timeout(function(){ return jqElem.html(); }, 0);
```

P.S.

You could pass template directly into the `$compile` function, but note that `.html()` will return inner HTML, so you may need to do something like the following to get the full template:

```
return $timeout(function(){ return jqElem[0].outerHTML; }, 0);
```

Comment: You can pass `template` directly to `$compile`.

Comment: @zeroflagL If I pass the template directly, where should I get the compiled string from? $compile returns something different...

Comment: @heinob `result = $compile(template)($scope).html()`

Comment: @zeroflagL, @heinob, there are a few problems with this solution! The `.html()` returns uncompiled template. I will ammend the answer to deal with it.

Comment: Nevermind - I see now that you dealt with it with $timeout as well :)

Comment: You are absolutely right about the digest cycle. I was too focused on the passing the template. But the template is no longer uncompiled at this point. The watchers haven't been called yet. +1

Answer (score 0):

In case if don't need directive interpretation:
Use `$interpolate`. Then don't need `$compile` and `$scope`. Related: [Compile a template without passing scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25212851/compile-a-template-without-passing-scope)

```
var html = '<div> {{item}} </div>' // or $templateCache.get('myTemplate.html') too
var vars = { item: 'John' };
var result = $interpolate(html)(vars);
// result = '<div> John </div>'
```